# characteristic curves tangent and gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

In the PDE $aU_x+bU_y = 0$.This is equivalent to  $\frac a{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}U_x+ \frac b{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}U_y = 0$.
 $\langle\frac a{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}, \frac b{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}\rangle$.$\nabla U=0$.
Then I can say that this is the directional derivative of U in the direction of $\widehat {\langle a,b \rangle}$.
This implies that the rate of change of $U$ in the direction of  $\widehat{\langle a,b \rangle }$=0.That is we are on a **level surface**. Since the gradient is perpendicular to the level surface and the dot product is zero, tangent to the level curve at that point is orthogonal to the gradient.

Is there a relationship between the tangent to the level surface and the direction of the directional derivative?
   Because in characteristic curves method I have seen that it says that   "The directonal derivative in the direction of the vector $\langle a,b \rangle$ is zero. The curves on the xy plane with $\langle a,b \rangle$ as **tangent vectors** have slopes$\frac ba.$ Thus $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac ba$ ".Please explain the *relationship of directional derivative and its tangent vector*.

In the PDE $aU_x+bU_y+cU = 0$ .This also has the directional derivative in the direction $\widehat {\langle a,b \rangle}$.
But here  the rate of change of U in the direction of  $\widehat{\langle a,b\rangle}$ is not zero.
That is we are **not** in  a level surface.  Hence can I say that the $\nabla U $ is perpendicular to the surface and the tangent at each point is in the direction $\langle a,b \rangle$.
I don't understand the relationship of **characteristic curves have with the gradient and the tangent plane.**

Comment: From what you know about the dot product, $\vec{n}\cdot\nabla U=|\nabla U|\cos\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between the gradient and the direction in which you are taking the derivative. The above a special case. Of course, the fact that $\nabla U$ points perpendicular to the level surface, is one of the fundamental properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a scalar function $U$, a point $x_0$ and a vector $v$, and $\gamma$ is a curve such that $\gamma(t_0) = x_0$, $\gamma'(t_0) = v$, then it holds
$$
   \frac{d}{dt}_{|t=t_0} U(\gamma(t)) = \frac{\partial U}{\partial v} (x_0) = U_x(x_0) v_x + U_y(x_0) v_y = \nabla U(x_0) \cdot v
   .
$$

This contains all the information you need.In particular: the directional derivative along a direction $v$ is the scalar product of the gradient of $U$ with the vector $v$.

You first example with $v=(a,b)$ can be written as $\frac{\partial U}{\partial v} = 0$ which says that the function $U$ is constant in the direction $v$.

In the second example you have $\frac{\partial U}{\partial v} = c U$ or $\nabla U \cdot v = c U$ which says that the scalar product of the gradient of $U$ with the direction $v$ is equal to $U$. This cannot be simplified further... you cannot say which is the direction of the level sets, because you don't know the magnitude of the gradient.

Comment: I don't understand what is done in the first expression